# How to update entire Array state in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement dynamic search which displays cards based on the input text in the search bar. I have a `cards` Array which has some static data in it, when a user type something in the search bar then it will trigger an `onChange` function that will search the `cards` array and display the results. Every thing is fine upto here as far as i know.

Below is my code sample.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import update from "react-addons-update";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import a from "a.jpg";

export default class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      search: "",
      results: [],   --> Tried sending results to new array which worked fine
      cards: [
        {
          id: "1",
          img: a,
          title: "Lorem ipsum",
          text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          img: a,
          title: "Lorem ipsum",
          text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          img: a,
          title: "Lorem ipsum",
          text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        },
        {
          id: "4",
          img: a,
          title: "Lorem ipsum",
          text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        },
        {
          id: "5",
          img: a,
          title: "Lorem ipsum",
          text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        },
        {
          id: "6",
          img: a,
          title: "Lorem ipsum",
          text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    const searchtext = e.target.value;
    let card = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.cards.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.cards[i].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchtext) > -1) {
        card.push(this.state.cards[i]);
      }
    }
    // const final = update(this.state, { cards: { $set: cards } }); --> Tried update but no luck
    this.setState({
      search: searchtext,
      cards: card,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div>
          <div className="input-group md">
            <div className="input"></div>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search"
              aria-label="Search"
              value={this.state.search}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row products align-items-center">
          {this.state.cards.map((element) => (
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-4" key={element.id}>
              <Card>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={element.img} />
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{element.title}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>{element.text}</Card.Text>
                  <a
                    className="btn"
                    type="submit"
                    href="/details"
                  >
                    Details
                  </a>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After getting the results i am updating the `cards` Array with the new results.

**Problem**
This is where it is not updating the `cards` array state perfectly. I have tried using [immutability helpers](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html#updating-a-value-based-on-its-current-one) but no luck. But its working when i am creating a new Array rather than sending results to existing data Array(i.e.`cards`).

Any help is appreicated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think its happening because when you are updating the state, the component remount and then the constructor gets called and clears the state and the list and set the default one which set by you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put the `onChange` function in a `ComponentDidMount` Block for it to catch changes. I had this same issue with updating state from a Firebase Realtime Database and when I finally put the `onChange` function in a the `ComponentDidMount` block, it worked.

```
 componentDidMount(){
    //Call onChange and setState here
  }
```